# responsive hamburger navbar not working, does not collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, hamburger-menu

am working on a project and need my navigation bar scaled to a hamburger menu for mobile view. I got most of it done but the navigation is not collapsing within the hamburger bar for some reason. been tweaking a lot last hours and haven't found the solution yet.

my js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jr01pvkL/8/

code is probably messy because it is part of a bigger project and i'm a beginner.

html

```
<header>
    <nav class="floatfix nav">
        <div id="hamburgerknop">
            <span id="hamburger">&#9776;</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="naar homepage">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="naar homepage">Over Ons</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="naar homepage">Producten</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="naar homepage">Workshop</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="naar homepage">Klanten</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="naar homepage">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="icon-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="icon icon-mono facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=nl" class="icon icon-mono twitter"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://plus.google.com" class="icon icon-mono googleplus"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="icon icon-mono instagram"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
body {
    font: 100%/1 "Coves", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(246,246,226);
    background-color: rgb(246,246,226);
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    /*background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);*/
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    height: 150px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
}
.logo {
    z-index: 12;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.nav {
    z-index: 11;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.non-transparent {
    z-index: 11;
    background-color: rgb(31,15,16) !important;
}
.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
}
.nav li {

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 120px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav li a {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    line-height: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 25px 11px 24px;
}
.nav li a:hover {
    color: rgb(212,192,152);
}
.icon-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 44px;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 44px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .icon-nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    /* Hamburger-knop voor mobiele navigatie */
    #hamburgerknop {
        background: rgba(31,15,16, 0.35);
        padding: 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    #hamburgerknop span {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 4px 3px;
        position: relative;
        color: rgb(246,246,226);
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: .8;
    }
    .nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(31,15,16);
    }
    .nav li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #E44D26;
        border-top: 1px solid #f17b54;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .nav li a {
        display: inline !important;
        background: none !important;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .nav {
        clear: both;
    }
}
.expand {
    display: block !important;
}
```

jquery(in html footer)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#hamburgerknop').click(function() {
        $('.nav').toggleClass('expand');
    });
});
```

Tnx!

Comment: looking for this ? https://jsfiddle.net/jr01pvkL/17/

Comment: Always end your statements with ";"! Else it might not get this code executed `jQuery(function($){
             $( '#hamburgerknop' ).click(function(){
             $('.nav').toggleClass('expand');
             });
        });` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is working fine you just need to add some css in media query like

```
  .main-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .expand .main-nav {
    display: block;
  }
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/jr01pvkL/18/)